# What's up with all the squid3 errors in any Ubuntu based 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, squid

What's up with the squid3 error on updates for the last few months?

```
Creating Squid HTTP proxy 3.x spool directory structure
2015/09/24 07:12:00| aclParseAclList: ACL name 'local_net' not found.
FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid3/squid.conf line 7162: http_access allow local_net
Squid Cache (Version 3.3.8): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.008 seconds = 0.008 user + 0.000 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 18144 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
dpkg: error processing package squid3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid3
```

And why is squid3 there to cause the problem in the first place?

Comment: "why is squid3 there" ... uh, because you installed it? I don't have any problems with my `squid3`. If you don't want it, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You, or a script, has corrupted the configuration file `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`. This causes squid3 to fail to start. So squid3 is treated as not properly installed by the packaging system, and you are told about this every time you apply updates.

If you didn't install squid3 directly yourself, then perhaps some package or other program that requires it did.

As @muru said, if you don't need it, you can remove the package. As squid3 isn't correctly running on your system anyway, you shouldn't miss anything.